# abortBroadcast() in Android 6.0

Tags: android

I'm creating SMS app and want to abortBroadcast() to stop sms go to default sms app. It is working fine in Android 4.2 Version but not working in Android 6.0

I have set the max priority.

```
<receiver android:name=".sms.ReceiveSMS" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

targetsdk = 4.2

Answer (score 1):

You cannot block the default SMS app from getting the message on Android 4.4+. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#SMS) and [this official blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html).

Comment: It is compulsory to do so. Any solution?

Comment: @Nothing: No, sorry.

Comment: then How can I delete sms from the inbox? I mean receiving sms should be deleted before going to app's inbox?

Comment: @Nothing: You cannot delete the message from the inbox, either. The user's chosen SMS client receives *all* messages on Android 4.4+. This is covered in the materials that I linked to in my answer.

Comment: the last question. I'm sending sms from my app but why it still goes in the default app as the sender.

Comment: @Nothing: There is only one OS-level SMS provider. All sent SMS messages go there, AFAIK, regardless of what app sends them.

Comment: Is there any way to modify that SMS?

Comment: @Nothing: You are the one that sent the SMS ("I'm sending sms from my app"). There should be nothing that needs to be modified after sending it. If you want to make changes to the message, change what you are sending.